# “Could not find default endpoint element that references contract”

Tags: wcf, error-handling, endpoint

While calling webservice during uninstallation of windows application I am getting error as

> Could not find endpoint element that references contract 
>   ServiceReference2.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration 
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for 
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name
>   could be found in the client element.

I am using Installer class in which I am calling webservice client. Following is code of installer.cs

Source code :

```
namespace webMiner 
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class demoInstaller : Installer
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=comp;User Id=abc;Password=******;");

    public demoInstaller():base()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

         AfterUninstall += new InstallEventHandler(AfterUninstallEventHandler);

    }


    public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
        Int32 flag = -1;
        string keyName = "";

            RegistryKey regeditkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("sevenuser", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        keyName = regeditkey.GetValue("currentuser").ToString();

            webMiner.ServiceReference2.Service1Client sc = new webMiner.ServiceReference2.Service1Client();

            flag = sc.unInstallOperation(keyName);


    }

}
```

}

Where unInstallOperation() will call webservice operation which contains updation of account.

How to solve this issue?
Really feedup with this issue

I have no problem when i call serviceclient from another page or from another class file it give me problem when I am calling during uninstallation of application i.e in Installer class. This is app.config client configuration code that i have used

source code:

```
  <client> 

  <endpoint address="http://companyfind.info/RegWcfService/Service1.svc" 
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
      contract="IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />

   </client>
```

Is there any need to add this in web.config file of web service??

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to use the name of your endpoint when you are instatiating Service1Client

```
var sc = new webMiner.ServiceReference2.Service1Client("BasicHttpBinding_IService1");
```

Or, as it was in my case, you have your another class in another project in solution and two app.config classes. So, you need to copy/paste the desription af enpoints and bindings in main app.config.

Comment: Ok, that worked for me, but that can't POSSIBLY be the proper solution. There must be a better practice. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the service reference, and check if client configuration is in the startup project config file.

Comment: is there any need to add the client code given above in web.config file of web service??

Comment: tried to update service reference and client configuration is in startup project config file only but it was of no use